# Movies purchased on itunes

Tags: macbook-pro

Why can't I watch my purchased itune movies offline on my MacBook Pro?
no wifi no movie yet I have purchased all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can. The content needs to be read from somewhere though, so you will need to download the multimedia directly to your hard drive. You can do so directly via the `iTunes.app` that typically lives in the dock at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: When I purchased them I downloaded them. How many times do I have to do that?

Comment: Depends; did you originally download to that same device? Or a different device? You need to locate the actual file.